# How do I build a switch-on circuit triggered by small signals, which will supply voltage for another circuit?

Tags: power-supply, power, amplifier, signal, circuit-design

The thing is, I have a small signal ([-5mV,5mV] up to [-35mV,35mV]) which is filtered and amplified by a conditioning circuit. But it all runs continually, and I should be able to power on the conditioning circuit only if there's something to amplify, so I can save battery.

Comment: Can you provide the schematic of the conditioning circuit? An answer would probably be very dependent upon the particulars. A top of the head idea would be to use a peak detector circuit into a comparator which would enable the power supply to the rest of the circuit using a FET or something...

Comment: Um, OK, but what is the spec?  Under what conditions do you want to power up this other circuit?  What voltage/current does it take?  What supplies are available?  It should be obvious that at least some of this information is needed.  Closing this question as *unclear* in its present form.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever circuit you use to monitor the input to determine when to switch on the rest of the circuits still needs continuous power to do the monitoring.  Depending on the source impedance of the input signal (unknown), its bandwidth (unknown), its signal-to-noise ratio (unknown), and whether monitoring only the positive half cycles is good enough (unknown), the monitor circuit could be as simple as a single CMOS opamp acting as a very low power comparator.  A potential problem is that most CMOS opamps have average to poor input errors, plus those errors drift within the operating temperature range (unknown).